# What is the best way to host videos for a website?

Tags: web, video, hosting

We are going to create a website and app for members where they can watch videos we have produced. The cost of hosting these videos seems to be very high. In terms of price, is it beneficial for us to have a CDN when most of our audience will be from the same area? I don't know how to solve this in the best (and cheapest) possible way..

(sorry if my writing is bad but english is not my native language)

Comment: "The cost of hosting these videos seems to be very high" The cost of doing it yourself will be just as high. You will just be paying the hosting company/cloud provider for storage CPU and bandwidth instead. The added benefit video companies provide is solving the hundreds of additional problems with streaming video that you have not encountered yet. Video on the internet is extremely difficult to do well.

Answer (score 0):

Host them on YouTube and set the videos as unlisted so they can only be accessed by a direct link. You can still embed them and get metrics on who is watching them. It's free and fast.

Comment: We are going to make our own custom video player, and you can't do that by embedding the videos from YouTube. I don't think it will look professional if we host them on YouTube either.

Comment: I paid a few thousand dollars to go to a coding bootcamp and all of their training videos were hosted on youtube. Lots of people do it to save on storage and server resources to play the videos. 

Otherwise, your best bet will be just looking for a COLO DataCenter that is regionally close to your customer base.